# Extract specific nodes from XML

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML file like below:

```
<catalog>
  <cd Id="2">
    <title>Title2</title>
    <artist>artist2</artist>
    <company>
      <companyName>Company2</companyName>
      <companyAddress1>street1</companyAddress1>
      <companyAddress2>street2</companyAddress2>
      <companyCity>City2</companyCity>
    </company>
    <price>12.90</price>
    <year>1987</year>
  </cd>
  <cd Id="3">
    <title>Title3</title>
    <artist>artist3</artist>
    <company>
      <companyName>Company3</companyName>
      <companyAddress1>street1</companyAddress1>
      <companyAddress2>street2</companyAddress2>
      <companyCity>City3</companyCity>
    </company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1984</year>
  </cd>
</catalog>
```

I want to filter this source XML based on Id attribute in  node and create a new XML file something like:

```
<catalog>
  <cd Id="2">
    <title>Title2</title>
    <artist>artist2</artist>
    <company>
      <companyName>Company2</companyName>
    </company>
    <price>12.90</price>
  </cd>
  <cd Id="3">
    <title>Title3</title>
    <artist>artist3</artist>
    <company>
      <companyName>Company3</companyName>
    </company>
    <price>9.90</price>
  </cd>
</catalog>
```

The source file is too huge so I guess I need to go with XmlReader. But I am unable to figure out a simple way to filter based on Id and extract the required nodes. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing something like [XSLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) might be your friend.  It's specifically designed to transform XML to other formats (including other XML formats).

Comment: [Show me the(your) code](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/), so we can help you get better instead of using our code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is exactly what you want:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("File path");//Load XML file

//Delete all elements in company except companyName
xdoc.Descendants("company").Elements().Where(x => x.Name != "companyName").Remove();

//Delete year
xdoc.Descendants("year").Remove();

xdoc.Save("File path");//Overwrite the XML file with the new result
```